# Renaming of the endpoint class caused deploying fail on Wildfly

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly

I renamed endpoint class in my project, rebuilt, redeployed it on Wildfly, but when I try to enable it failed with this error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.websocket.DeploymentException: UT003023: Multiple endpoints with the same logical mapping PathTemplate
```

How to avoid this problem or clean deployments?

Comment: Use maven -clean, remove old deployment (undeploy), restart jBoss ...